# How to return if else value from loop in other class

Tags: java

i have a two class.In class A i am calling another class B method which has if/else statement in for loop .Now i have to return the value of if/else each time on class A

Class A

```
    public class ClassA extends ClassB {
    public void checkSuiteInExcelToRun() throws IOException {
    getResult();
    System.out.println("po: "+getResult());
    }
    }
```

Class B

```
public class  ClassB {

public String getResult(){

        int sheetIndex=wb.getSheetIndex(wsName);
        int rowNum = "3";
            int colNum ="3";
        for(int i=1;i<rowNum;i++){
                Row Suiterow = ws.getRow(i);
                for(int j=1;i<colNum;j++){
                     op =Suiterow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("get value:----"+op  );
                if(op.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                    System.out.println("op is  "+op);
                break;
                }
                else if (op.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    System.out.println("op is  " + op);
                    break;
                }
                }

            }
            return op;
}
```

Here I am calling getresult() from Class A.Now suppose for loop 1 cell value is i.e op= y  then it has too return "Y"  to class A.Now for  loop 2, cell value is i.e op= N  then it has too return "N" to Class A ...and so on .But currently what is happening , it is returning the last loop value only ie in above condition returning only last value "N"

I want all loop value should return to Class A

Comment: Then return a `Map<Integer, String>` where the `Integer` represents your current line. fill the `Map` at each iteration and return it.

Comment: Can you not return an array or list?

Comment: But i wanted like execute loop 1 and return its value to class A ,and then execute loop 2 and again return it value to Class A... and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to my posted question.I am posting this so that other people can refer it

make changes in Class B only

Class B

```
public class  ClassB {

public String getResult(){

        int sheetIndex=wb.getSheetIndex(wsName);
        int rowNum = "3";
            int colNum ="3";
        for(int i=1;i<rowNum;i++){
                Row Suiterow = ws.getRow(i);
                for(int j=1;i<colNum;j++){
                     op =Suiterow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("get value:----"+op  );
                if(op.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                    System.out.println("op is  "+op);
                return op;
                }
                else if (op.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    System.out.println("op is  " + op);
                    return op;
                }
                }

            }
            return op;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your queries:

It is returning last value **only**: It is returning only 1 value because once the return statement is encountered, the current method stops executing and control is passed back to the calling function.

So you should store the values in an Arraylist and return the arrayList instead of individual values.

If you want to avoid using collections(due to some reason), you can use the for loop inside your class A instead.

Comment: can  i do it like this if(op.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                    System.out.println("op is  "+op); return op;
                break;
                }
                else if (op.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    System.out.println("op is  " + op); return op;
                    break;
                }

Comment: You can do this if you are running a for loop from class A. In that case for each i getResult will return a value to checkSuiteInExcelToRun

Comment: Also there is no use of break if you are using return as that line won't be executed

Comment: ok then how can i do it. Is it not possible like i wanted without using array

Comment: I already gave you 2 approaches, either run a for loop in class A or return all the vals from class B in an array/collection